# Angular JS - Is there any way to dynamically select templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

i have a problem with angularjs router function:

How can I dynamically choose templates for my app.

I have an app which is completely drive by `'its api's'`. The api's contains `'template info along with them'.`

For example api:

```
 [{
"rootName" : "home1",
"pageTitle"   : "Home1",
"templateName" : "template_home_1"
    },
   {
"rootName" : "home2",
"pageTitle"   : "Home2",
"templateName" : "template_home_2"
   },
    {
"rootName" : "home3",
"pageTitle"   : "Home3",
"templateName" : "template_home_2"
  }]
```

The reason for this is reuasbility, and flexibility for choice UI's.

How i can do this with Angular. Is there any way to dynamically select templates.

My router goes like this:

```
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                  $routeProvider
                   .when('/mainpage/:pageid',
                    {   
                       controller:'mainpageController',
                          template : function (pageid) {
                          //this information is avilable at my api
                       }
                     })
                   .otherwise({redirectTo:'/mainpage/home'});  

                   });
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Are you trying to do an async call in the template function?

Comment: yes @ivarni.. template need to be dynamically selected... I m new to Angular js..

Comment: The docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#usage does not mention anything about asynchronous support for template functions, so I am not sure how possible that is. If the routes are reasonably static I would perhaps consider fetching them in advance.

Comment: Could it possible to initialize router after i fetch data from sever..  At that time i can write some custom functions to get template  information..

Comment: That's the problem, you don't have access to the `$http` service in the config-step of the lifecycle. How about moving some logic to the server and have the template-function return something like `/templates/page/home1`, `/templates/page/home2` and then lookup the correct template on the serverside and return it? Or wait for someone smarter than me to come along :)

Comment: thanks @ivarni.. helpful information.. And waiting for some better answers...

Comment: How if i go for switch case and select templates viva src ??

Comment: hi @ivarni:  how can i achieve this with angular: <div class="outer" ng-repeat="data in content">
 <div class="inner-top">
  {{index data}}
 </div>
 <div class="inner-bottom">
  {{index+1 data}}
 </div>
</div>

Comment: here every loop two data need to selected and data should not repeat. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use templateurl, and make the server serve the template,

```
.when('/mainpage/:pageid',{templateUrl:'/tpl/:pageid'})
```

You can modify the templates on the serverside. The server will pick up the route and decide what templates to display.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to implement dynamic templates on client side, but on server side I can use a dynamic template engine like JADE to serve role/parameter based templates.

Comment: Could it possible to initialize router after i fetch data from sever.. At that time i can write some custom functions to get template information..

Comment: U can use something like when('/mainpage/:pageid',
                    {   
                       controller:'mainpageController',
                          templateurl : 'tpl/:id'
                     })
and let the server decide which template to throw. I am currently using this architecture with node mongo and angularjs.

Comment: I think you can write some custom directive to load async stuff inside your code, I have seen that in angular-googlemaps but not sure how it was implemented.

Comment: How if i go for switch case and select templates viva src ?? –

Comment: You can try directives like this but I am not sure, never worked with directives. I am just guessing it might get your work done. `<mydirective ng-rootname=root1 ng-tplname=tpl1 ng=pagetitle=title>`

Answer (score 0):

Some how managed to solve this by using switch and custom directive.

```
<div ng-switch on="data.templateName">
 <div ng-switch-when="template_1">
    <template_1></template_1>
 </div>
 <div ng-switch-when="template_2">
    <template_2></template_2>
 </div>
 <div ng-switch-default>{{data}}</div>
</div>
```

and defined by directive as

```
 demoApp.directive('template1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/template1.html'
    };
});
```

Dont know if have any better methods.
Will be looking forward to have alternative better solutions.. Thank you..